# Intermittent System.IO.IOException while using SmtpClient

Tags: .net, smtp, smtpclient

I'm having a problem with .NET's `SmtpClient`.  Every so often, the `Send` method throws the following exception:

```
System.Net.Mail.SmtpException: Failure sending mail.
System.IO.IOException: Unable to read data from the transport connection: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host.
System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host
   at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.Receive(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size, SocketFlags socketFlags)
   at System.Net.Sockets.NetworkStream.Read(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
```

We're averaging around 550 emails per hour (or ~9 emails per minute) in production, and the problem never seems to occur in QA.

Every email is sent like this:

```
using (var newMessage = new MailMessage { ReplyTo = new MailAddress(supportEmail, "Support") })
{
    newMessage.To.Add(recipients);
    newMessage.From = new MailAddress(fromEmail, "From Name");
    newMessage.Subject = message.Subject;
    newMessage.Body = body;
    using (var mailHost = new SmtpClient())
    {
        mailHost.Send(newMessage);
    }
}
```

Note that we're disposing all resources, we aren't using SSL, and we're loading the Smtp settings from `web.config`, which look like this:

```
   <mailSettings>
      <smtp from="validEmail"  deliveryMethod="Network"  >        
        <network defaultCredentials ="false" host="dedicatedSmtpServer" port="port"/>
      </smtp>
    </mailSettings>
```

Some notes I've put together:

1. Every email is sent with its own instance of `SmtpClient`.  This is true even in bulk-sending scenarios.  I've read that this could have performance implications since the sockets aren't pooled.  However, performance seems to be adequate when it *does* work.
2. We're using .NET 4, so the bug where `SmtpClient` wasn't terminating connections is fixed.
3. According to a colleague (I don't have access to the server logs myself), the SMTP server doesn't log connection attempts for the emails that fail (although the successful emails do have log entries)

Answer (score 0):

Your code has nothing to do with this. This particular error:

> Unable to read data from the transport connection: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host.

basically means that the remote end has terminated the socket. The 'forcibly" just means it was done in an unusual way but it is still the remote end. It may be due to how long the socket stayed open, so implementing a socket pool definitely is a good idea.

Comment: What's strange is that the SMTP server doesn't have any record of the attempted connection, though.  In addition, these are very short-lived sockets -- we only ever use them to send exactly one email

Comment: You are likely looking in the incorrect log file. Which log file are you trying on the SMTP server side?

Comment: Not me -- my colleague.  I can't get access, unfortunately.  But the successful emails do show in the same log file, so I'd be surprised if it was the wrong one.  I'll see if I can verify.

Comment: If you are opening and closing a socket for every single message, you could be over burdening the SMTP server and effectivly DoSing yourself out of the ability to connect.

Comment: At 9 emails per minute?  Perhaps...I was thinking maybe trying to switch over to using a pickup directory instead if that's the case.  Does anyone know if that has any effect on throughput?

Comment: The log file is correct @bc004346.  In addition, we've discovered that the problem only started once we took ownership of the software (new web server, new mail server, same code)